# Geocoder flutter not very efficient

Tags: flutter, geocoder

I encounter some trouble with Geocoder as flutter package.
I can notice that it doesn't fit well for some France town and most of time it doesn't find it.
I've got a google api's key but I can't find anything to convert a town to a postal code and vice versa.
Do you know an api on Google to make it please?
Thank you